# Searching in log files and record their file names in a text file in two different sections depending on string found in log file

Tags: batch-file

I want to write a batch file which can search for `Script Compiled Successfully` in all log files in the current directory and print the file names containing this string into `Summarized.txt` in one section as well as as the file names of all log files which do not contain the string into a second section.

I have a batch code below which can print the files containing this string into `Summarized.txt`. I want to modify it so it can print the file names plus a predefined message. And files not containing the string should be included also in `Summarized.txt`.

If all files contain the search string then output message `None` should be written under section `Script Not Compiled Successfully` into `Summarized.txt`.

The output to Summarized.txt should be like below:

```
**********Script Compiled Successfully********************

1234.log
3456.log
7899.log

**********Script Not Compiled Successfully****************

8888.log
6666.log

**********End*********************************************
```

Here is the batch code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
@echo off
findstr /m /C:"Script Compiled Successfully" *.log > Summarized.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
    echo Found! logged files into Summarized.txt
) else (
    echo No matches found
)

@pause
```

Comment: It would help to see the log file, as the format of the file will determine the code to use.

Comment: The log file contains all messages spool from Oracle. In the batch file, I just to need to search literal string 'Script Compiled Successfully' which I already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the batch file for this task. It is very simple.

I added some comments above code which I think needs a little explanation.

```
@echo off
rem Delete temporarily used files if exist from a previous
rem (aborted) run as it is important that those 2 files do
rem not exist because of the two conditions after the loop.
if exist Success.txt del Success.txt
if exist Failed.txt del Failed.txt

rem Run command findstr on each log file individually as it must be
rem also recorded in which log files the string could not be found.
for %%F in (*.log) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /M "/C:Script Compiled Successfully" "%%F" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %%F>>Failed.txt
    ) else (
        echo %%F>>Success.txt
    )
)

echo **********Script Compiled Successfully********************>Summarized.txt
echo.>>Summarized.txt

rem Was the string found in any log file?
if exist Success.txt (
    type Success.txt >>Summarized.txt
    del Success.txt
) else (
    echo None>>Summarized.txt
)

echo.>>Summarized.txt
echo **********Script Not Compiled Successfully****************>>Summarized.txt
echo.>>Summarized.txt

rem Was the string not found in any log file?
if exist Failed.txt (
    type Failed.txt >>Summarized.txt
    del Failed.txt
) else (
    echo None>>Summarized.txt
)

echo.>>Summarized.txt
echo **********End*********************************************>>Summarized.txt
```